# How to assign each line in a text to an array in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I have a text file named "raj.txt" containing following content:

---

raj
magesh
popey
ravi

---

How can I assign each word to array element?

`a[0]=raj
a[1]=magesh
a[2]=popey
a[3]=ravi`

Comment: each line or word in a line to array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   set -- $line
   echo "$1"
   echo "$2"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell support array, like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`, try:

```
$ array=($(<filename))
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[0]}"
raj
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[1]}"
magesh
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[2]}"
popey
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[3]}"
ravi
```